# Sharepoint Search: Exclude deprecated terms and corresponding documents from search results

Tags: search, sharepoint, metadata, managed

I have defined Terms (managed metadata) and created the search refiners based on that.
My requirement is when I deprecate a term the refiner should be hidden and the search results should not show the documents associated with that term

Comment: i would assume that a full crawl would hide them after completion?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Verthosa. I believed the same. But full crawl does is not hiding the documents associated with deprecated terms. I am not sure whether or not there is a way to modify search result sources query and check for isDeprecated flag of the term.

Comment: The problem is not solved yet. The document library contains items for which I have deprecated the term but it is still shown in the search result :(